# Right-clicking on the title bar of a window shows extra options, but how can you see these options for windows that don't have title bars?

Tags: 20.04, xubuntu, xfce

Right-clicking on the title bar of a window shows handy options like "Resize" and "Always on Top". However, not all windows have title bars. How can I make this menu show for such windows?

Here is an example of such a title bar
[image]

and such a menu
[image]

and here is a Firefox window without a title bar
[image]

Comment: If you right click the icon in the Task Bar you should see all the same options for all running Windows or Applications.

Comment: @Terrance Not in my experience. Doing that only gives me six options - (Un)Minimise, (Un)Maximise, Move, Resize, Always On Top, and Close. What I have in mind gives about 12, such as Roll Window Up.

Comment: Can yu give an example of a window without title bar? Also in applications with a GTK headerbar, the menu can be displayed by right-clicking anywhere in the header bar.

Comment: @vanadium Sure. See edit.

Comment: It will also be useful to post your desktop environment: the screenshot suggest you use Nemo. For mozilla products, the lack of such menu is known: just turn the traditional title bar on if you want such menu

Comment: @vanadium Xfce. It's on the tags.

Comment: @vanadium apparently alt+space opens it on firefox without the titlebar too... I remember hating this but I guess I unwittingly turned the title bar back on at some point and stopped caring...

Comment: @WU-TANG yes, it is only the right-click menu that does not work on mozilla apps. Alt+space works everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alt + Space does it. No idea if there's any other way.